# javascript: why to "sign-prefix" a variable?

Tags: javascript, syntax

i'm currently looking at a little 3rd-party javascript library and i see a lot of "sign-prefixed" variables in it:

```
function_call(+value);
```

i know, that you can swap the sign, if you prefix a variable with '-', but why to prefix something with a '+' -- it doesn't do anything to the value, no?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `+` forces the `value` to become a Number.

```
>>> "1"
"1"
>>> +"1"
1
```

Comment: i understand **shame-on-me** ... i could have figured out this on my own. thanks for your help :-)