# what's the use of having plus sign infront of an expression

Tags: javascript, expression, operator-keyword

```
eq: function( i ) {
    var len = this.length,
        j = +i + ( i < 0 ? len : 0 );
    return this.pushStack( j >= 0 && j < len ? [ this[j] ] : [] );
},
```

i'm new to programming in general, but what is the purpose of having a single + sign infront of an expression, i've seen these in jquery library a lot.

```
+(expression)
```

these i'd understand, as they are negative:

```
-(1);// -1
```

Comment: More answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470973/single-plus-operator-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable

Comment: Yet more answers; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880902/javascript-why-to-sign-prefix-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It converts the string number to actual number in the expression.

```
console.log(typeof +"1");        // number
console.log("1" + "1");          // 11
console.log(+"1" + +"1");        // 2
console.log("1.3" + "1.546");    // 1.31.546
console.log(+"1.3" + +"1.546");  // 2.846
```

Quoting from the [ECMA 5.1 Standard Specifications for + operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6),

> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.

Internally, a JavaScript string will be converted to a number based on [these rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1) specified in the ECMA 5.1 standards.

**Edit:** As per the [`Number`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.1.1) specifications, it also internally uses the same `ToNumber` to convert its parameter to a number. So, technically `Number(<number string>)` is the same as `+<number string>`.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to convert a value to a floating point number.

```
+"123.25" + 2 = 125.25
```

Similar is

```
(x | 0)
```

that is instead used to conver to an integer (the operation is a bit-wise or with zero).

In asm.js can these forms are used also as type declarations for parameters and locals.